# Connecting to Azure using SQL Server 2012 and SSDT 2010

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-data-tools

Trying to connect to Azure using SQL Server 2012 and SSDT 2010 I receive the message "An incompatible SQL Server Version was detected. Is it possible to connect SSDT 2010 to the most recent version of Azure?

Answer (score 1):

No, SSDT for Visual Studio 2010 does not support connecting to Azure SQL DB V12 databases.  You'll need to use SSDT for Visual Studio 2012, SSDT for Visual Studio 2013 or SSDT for Visual Studio 2015 to connect to an Azure SQL DB V12 instance.